# Creating a reversed D3 stack bar chart

Tags: d3.js

Assuming I have data like this:

```
const data = [
  {
    month: 1
    apples: ...,
    bananas: ...,
    cherries: ...,
    dates: ...,
  },
  {
    month: 2
    apples: ...,
    bananas: ...,
    cherries: ...,
    dates: ...,
  },
  {
    month: 3
    apples: ...,
    bananas: ...,
    cherries: ...,
    dates: ...,
  }
]
```

Going for 12 months, using keys of `['apples','bananas','cherries','dates']`. The `d3.stack()` will produce an array for 4 bars with 12 sets of values. This makes sense. However, what if I wanted to create 12 bars with the keys broken up so it's sets of 4 values.

Is it possible to flip things on their heads in this fashion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to convert the data into the required format and flip the axis and data configurations in the chart as shown below.

**Existing :**

```js
var margin = {
  top: 20,
  right: 160,
  bottom: 35,
  left: 30
};

var width = 500 - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = 250 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");


/* Data in strings like it would be if imported from a csv */

var data = [{
    year: "2006",
    redDelicious: "10",
    mcintosh: "15",
    oranges: "9",
    pears: "6"
  },
  {
    year: "2007",
    redDelicious: "12",
    mcintosh: "18",
    oranges: "9",
    pears: "4"
  },
  {
    year: "2008",
    redDelicious: "05",
    mcintosh: "20",
    oranges: "8",
    pears: "2"
  },
  {
    year: "2009",
    redDelicious: "01",
    mcintosh: "15",
    oranges: "5",
    pears: "4"
  }
];

var parse = d3.time.format("%Y").parse;


// Transpose the data into layers
var dataset = d3.layout.stack()(["redDelicious", "mcintosh", "oranges", "pears"].map(function(fruit) {
  return data.map(function(d) {
    return {
      x: parse(d.year),
      y: +d[fruit]
    };
  });
}));


// Set x, y and colors
var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
  .domain(dataset[0].map(function(d) {
    return d.x;
  }))
  .rangeRoundBands([10, width - 10], 0.02);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
  .domain([0, d3.max(dataset, function(d) {
    return d3.max(d, function(d) {
      return d.y0 + d.y;
    });
  })])
  .range([height, 0]);

var colors = ["b33040", "#d25c4d", "#f2b447", "#d9d574"];


// Define and draw axes
var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(y)
  .orient("left")
  .ticks(5)
  .tickSize(-width, 0, 0)
  .tickFormat(function(d) {
    return d
  });

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(x)
  .orient("bottom")
  .tickFormat(d3.time.format("%Y"));

svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "y axis")
  .call(yAxis);

svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "x axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(xAxis);


// Create groups for each series, rects for each segment 
var groups = svg.selectAll("g.cost")
  .data(dataset)
  .enter().append("g")
  .attr("class", "cost")
  .style("fill", function(d, i) {
    return colors[i];
  });

var rect = groups.selectAll("rect")
  .data(function(d) {
    return d;
  })
  .enter()
  .append("rect")
  .attr("x", function(d) {
    return x(d.x);
  })
  .attr("y", function(d) {
    return y(d.y0 + d.y);
  })
  .attr("height", function(d) {
    return y(d.y0) - y(d.y0 + d.y);
  })
  .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
  .on("mouseover", function() {
    tooltip.style("display", null);
  })
  .on("mouseout", function() {
    tooltip.style("display", "none");
  })
  .on("mousemove", function(d) {
    var xPosition = d3.mouse(this)[0] - 15;
    var yPosition = d3.mouse(this)[1] - 25;
    tooltip.attr("transform", "translate(" + xPosition + "," + yPosition + ")");
    tooltip.select("text").text(d.y);
  });


// Draw legend
var legend = svg.selectAll(".legend")
  .data(colors)
  .enter().append("g")
  .attr("class", "legend")
  .attr("transform", function(d, i) {
    return "translate(30," + i * 19 + ")";
  });

legend.append("rect")
  .attr("x", width - 18)
  .attr("width", 18)
  .attr("height", 18)
  .style("fill", function(d, i) {
    return colors.slice().reverse()[i];
  });

legend.append("text")
  .attr("x", width + 5)
  .attr("y", 9)
  .attr("dy", ".35em")
  .style("text-anchor", "start")
  .text(function(d, i) {
    switch (i) {
      case 0:
        return "Anjou pears";
      case 1:
        return "Naval oranges";
      case 2:
        return "McIntosh apples";
      case 3:
        return "Red Delicious apples";
    }
  });


// Prep the tooltip bits, initial display is hidden
var tooltip = svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "tooltip")
  .style("display", "none");

tooltip.append("rect")
  .attr("width", 30)
  .attr("height", 20)
  .attr("fill", "white")
  .style("opacity", 0.5);

tooltip.append("text")
  .attr("x", 15)
  .attr("dy", "1.2em")
  .style("text-anchor", "middle")
  .attr("font-size", "12px")
  .attr("font-weight", "bold");
```

```css
svg {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
}

path.domain {
  stroke: none;
}

.y .tick line {
  stroke: #ddd;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

**New :**

```js
var margin = {
  top: 20,
  right: 160,
  bottom: 35,
  left: 30
};

var width = 500 - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = 250 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");


/* Data in strings like it would be if imported from a csv */

var data = [{
    fruit: "redDelicious",
    2006: "10",
    2007: "12",
    2008: "05",
    2009:  "01",
    2010: "02"
  },
  {
    fruit: "mcintosh",
    2006: "15",
    2007: "18",
    2008: "20",
    2009:  "15",
    2010: "10"
  },
  {
    fruit: "oranges",
    2006: "9",
    2007: "9",
    2008: "8",
    2009:  "5",
    2010: "4"
  },
  {
    fruit: "pears",
    2006: "6",
    2007: "4",
    2008: "2",
    2009: "4",
    2010: "2"   
  }
];

var legends = Object.keys(data[0]);
legends.splice(legends.indexOf('fruit'), 1);
// Transpose the data into layers
var dataset = d3.layout.stack()(legends.map(function(year) {
  return data.map(function(d) {
    return {
      x: d.fruit,
      y: +d[year]
    };
  });
}));


// Set x, y and colors
var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
  .domain(dataset[0].map(function(d) {
    return d.x;
  }))
  .rangeRoundBands([10, width - 10], 0.02);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
  .domain([0, d3.max(dataset, function(d) {
    return d3.max(d, function(d) {
      return d.y0 + d.y;
    });
  })])
  .range([height, 0]);

var colors = ["b33040", "#d25c4d", "#f2b447", "#d9d574","#6aa8e0"];


// Define and draw axes
var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(y)
  .orient("left")
  .ticks(5)
  .tickSize(-width, 0, 0)
  .tickFormat(function(d) {
    return d
  });

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(x)
  .orient("bottom")
  //.tickFormat(d3.time.format("%Y"));

svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "y axis")
  .call(yAxis);

svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "x axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(xAxis);


// Create groups for each series, rects for each segment 
var groups = svg.selectAll("g.cost")
  .data(dataset)
  .enter().append("g")
  .attr("class", "cost")
  .style("fill", function(d, i) {
    return colors[i];
  });

var rect = groups.selectAll("rect")
  .data(function(d) {
    return d;
  })
  .enter()
  .append("rect")
  .attr("x", function(d) {
    return x(d.x);
  })
  .attr("y", function(d) {
    return y(d.y0 + d.y);
  })
  .attr("height", function(d) {
    return y(d.y0) - y(d.y0 + d.y);
  })
  .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
  .on("mouseover", function() {
    tooltip.style("display", null);
  })
  .on("mouseout", function() {
    tooltip.style("display", "none");
  })
  .on("mousemove", function(d) {
    var xPosition = d3.mouse(this)[0] - 15;
    var yPosition = d3.mouse(this)[1] - 25;
    tooltip.attr("transform", "translate(" + xPosition + "," + yPosition + ")");
    tooltip.select("text").text(d.y);
  });


// Draw legend
var legend = svg.selectAll(".legend")
  .data(colors)
  .enter().append("g")
  .attr("class", "legend")
  .attr("transform", function(d, i) {
    return "translate(30," + i * 19 + ")";
  });

legend.append("rect")
  .attr("x", width - 18)
  .attr("width", 18)
  .attr("height", 18)
  .style("fill", function(d, i) {
    return colors.slice().reverse()[i];
  });

legend.append("text")
  .attr("x", width + 5)
  .attr("y", 9)
  .attr("dy", ".35em")
  .style("text-anchor", "start")
  .text(function(d, i) {
    return legends.reverse()[i];
  });


// Prep the tooltip bits, initial display is hidden
var tooltip = svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "tooltip")
  .style("display", "none");

tooltip.append("rect")
  .attr("width", 30)
  .attr("height", 20)
  .attr("fill", "white")
  .style("opacity", 0.5);

tooltip.append("text")
  .attr("x", 15)
  .attr("dy", "1.2em")
  .style("text-anchor", "middle")
  .attr("font-size", "12px")
  .attr("font-weight", "bold");
```

```css
svg {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
}

path.domain {
  stroke: none;
}

.y .tick line {
  stroke: #ddd;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I did a combo of this and messed with the payload that's provided. I have some control over the response I'll get back as my team is building the API.